# Angularjs ui-mask with ng-pattern

Tags: regex, angularjs, ng-pattern, angularjs-ui-utils

below code is not working..

```
<input type="text"
       class="form-control input-sm"
       placeholder="hh:mm:ss"
       name="hhmmss"
       ng-model="data.hhmmss"
       ui-mask="99:99:99"
       ng-pattern="/^([0-2]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):?[0-5][0-9]:?[0-5][0-9]$/"
/>
```

when input value is `20:00:00`, then `formName.hhmmss.$error.pattern` is `true`.

if remove `ui-mask`:

```
<input type="text"
       class="form-control input-sm"
       placeholder="hh:mm:ss"
       name="hhmmss"
       ng-model="data.hhmmss"
       ng-pattern="/^([0-2]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):?[0-5][0-9]:?[0-5][0-9]$/"
    />
```

when input value is `20:00:00`, then `formName.hhmmss.$error.pattern` is `false`.

How can I use regex in `ng-pattern`?

Comment: Remove the ^ from the ng-pattern and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Removing the ^ from ng-pattern does not fix this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and altered the mask.js file to update the scope value on keypress.  There is a line of code which does this but isn't run all the time.

```
controller.$setViewValue(valUnmasked);
```

Update the if statement to the following:

```
if (valAltered || iAttrs.ngPattern) {
```

That will run "scope.apply" on keypress and update the model.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 1.3.19 changed behaviour of `ng-pattern` that breaks ui-mask.

Currently, ng-pattern directive validates `$viewValue` instead of `$modelValue` - [Reference in changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1319-glutinous-shriek-2015-09-15).

Angular team provided custom directive which reverts previous behavior. It is good workaround for this problem.

You have to add `pattern-model` attribute to fields when you use both `ui-mask` and `ng-pattern`.

```
<input type="text"
       class="form-control input-sm"
       placeholder="hh:mm:ss"
       name="hhmmss"
       ng-model="data.hhmmss"
       ng-pattern="/^([0-2]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):?[0-5][0-9]:?[0-5][0-9]$/"
       ui-mask="99:99:99"
       pattern-model
/>
```

Code of the directive (add it to your codebase):

```
.directive('patternModel', function patternModelOverwriteDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    priority: 1,
    compile: function() {
      var regexp, patternExp;

      return {
        pre: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
          if (!ctrl) return;

          attr.$observe('pattern', function(regex) {
            /**
             * The built-in directive will call our overwritten validator
             * (see below). We just need to update the regex.
             * The preLink fn guarantees our observer is called first.
             */
            if (angular.isString(regex) && regex.length > 0) {
              regex = new RegExp('^' + regex + '$');
            }

            if (regex && !regex.test) {
              //The built-in validator will throw at this point
              return;
            }

            regexp = regex || undefined;
          });

        },
        post: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
          if (!ctrl) return;

          regexp, patternExp = attr.ngPattern || attr.pattern;

          //The postLink fn guarantees we overwrite the built-in pattern validator
          ctrl.$validators.pattern = function(value) {
            return ctrl.$isEmpty(value) ||
              angular.isUndefined(regexp) ||
              regexp.test(value);
          };
        }
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Issue in ui-mask GitHub - [Reference](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask/issues/198).